# What is this device? What is this part's name and what does it do?

Tags: identification, components

Can anyone tell me what this is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a high power coax fitting - might be used for a broadcast transmitter output to antenna feed line.

Comment: Can you provide some context such as where you got it and what equipment was near that it may be associated with.

Comment: There was nothing.  The professor just handed us to guess what is it. I couldn’t find anything so I am now seeking for help. Cz i am curious

Comment: I think Peter Bennet is close, especially given the RCA symbol on the side.  They were big into radio and TV transmission (and reception) way back when.

Comment: What is the subject matter of the course you're taking?

Comment: please add a picture of the other end of the pipe

Comment: is that a hex screw visible in the second picture?

Comment: Another vote for  high-power radio transmitter "coax"

Comment: I'd have put it on my head and pretended I was a submarine hunting a battleship....

Comment: He said nothing about it. Just to figure it out

Comment: It's from ECE class. Electrical and computer Engineering

Comment: Damn. That's the biggest co-ax I've ever seen by several thousand times.

Comment: Old style Heliax.

Comment: See [here](https://worldradiohistory.com/Archive-Catalogs/RCA/RCA-Coaxial-Catalog-70s.pdf). I think vu2nan is on the right path.

Answer (score 6):

It's a rigid coaxial transmission line component (90° elbow, unflanged (copper) for the broadcast industry.

A rigid coaxial transmission line is used to couple a broadcast transmitter to its antenna.

Here's a catalogue of components of another make ([American Amplifier Technologies](https://www.americanamptech.com/collections/broadcast-equipment-and-accessories-1/elbows)).

Comment: +1, In this video some rigid coax connections are shown in an FM station: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJbMujVDpQU&t=228s

Comment: @Wesley Lee - Thank you very much for the video, Wesley.